# Publishing issue, Callkit is included even we are not using it

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, callkit

Good afternoon everyone today we have received a call from Apple saying that Callkit, included in our app, will block the app approval process.

Apple discovered an issue with Callkit and all the apps with a reference to callkit won't be published.

The problem is that we aren't using callkit but it's included in the assembly Xamarine.Ios , the main assembly for an Ios Xamarine project.

Is there a way to go over this problem by your opinion, by removing or similar stuff this reference?
Thank you very much for your appreciated help

Answer (score 4):

By default your device builds (including the one you submit to Apple) should have the managed linker enabled (with **Link SDK** setting).

That will remove any trace of CallKit (and a lot of other unused stuff) from the Xamarin.iOS.dll that ships with your application.

That is unless it's used elsewhere inside your application (or 3rd party code), in which case the linker won't be able to remove it.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true, because usually iOS apps build with the linker flag `-ObjC`, which links all Objective-C classes. So if there are Objective-C classes in the library that use a particular thing, then your app will link it, even if you don't use those classes.

Comment: It is because the *managed* linker runs before the AOT compiler, which will end up calling the *native* linker (but at that stage all trace of unused types/frameworks have been removed)..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had to use `find / -type f -exec grep -H 'CallKit' {} \;` inside your project folder to find which app/framework is using it. It was a third party framework using CallKit.