# Making a phone call iOS Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, app-store-connect, callkit

I have an app which enables an user to make phone call to a certain number. I am doing following:-

```
private void CallContact(string phone)
            {

                phone = phone.Replace(" ", "");

                var callURL = new NSUrl("tel:" + phone);


                try
                {
                    if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(callURL))
                    {
                        UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(callURL);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var av = new UIAlertView("Not supported",
                         "Calling is not supported on this device",
                         null,
                         "OK",
                         null);
                        av.Show();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return;
                }



            }
```

This works fine. But when I tried publishing the app, my app got rejected and the Apple team asked me the following:-

```
We noticed that your app has CallKit and CallKit Blocker enabled: 
⁃Which features of your app require CallKit and CallKit Blocker functionality? 
⁃Where, specifically, in the app would users access these features?
```

I am not using the CallKit functionality anywhere in my app. I searched SO and found that it is shipped with the Xamarin.iOS.dll . It is possible that the way I am making calls in my app uses the CallKit?

Sorry for bein a noob :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39751196/publishing-issue-callkit-is-included-even-we-are-not-using-it

Comment: @SushiHangover I have gone through that question already. I have implemented what is suggested as well. I just need to confirm since I am using the calling feature but that does not seem to use the CallKit.

Comment: @SushiHangover Also since I am new to iOS, I am not sure if the way I am making phone call uses the CallKit indirectly.

Comment: Opening the Dialer is not a part of CallKit/CallKit Blocker (these are VOIP features). Is the linker enabled in your release build configuration?

Comment: @SushiHangover it wasn't. I have created a new build with the linker enabled and will be submitting the new one for review. I needed to confirm so that I can reply them about my scenario.

Comment: @SushiHangover In my previously submitted binary, The Linker behavior was "Don't link", now I have changed it to "Link Framework SDK only". I hope that should solve the issue

Comment: Just tell them it was a build mistake and your app is not referencing CallKit in the new build....

Answer (score 1):

try this solution

```
partial void BtnContactBillingCall_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender)
        {
            var confirm = new UIAlertView("","Call "+ mobilenumber + " ?",null,"Cancel","Call");
            confirm.Show();
            confirm.Clicked +=    (object senderConfirm, UIButtonEventArgs e) => 
            {
                if(e.ButtonIndex ==0)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    var url = new Foundation.NSUrl("tel:"+mBillingPhoneNumber);
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url);
                }

            };
        }
```